# Can’t get auto-wifi-connection to work on Pi Zero W on boot

Tags: raspbian, wifi, ssh, internet, pi-zero-w

What I want:

- Every time the Pi starts, it should connect to the wifi
- I should be able to ssh into it via its IP

So, after a whole day of trying and searching, I managed to finally connect to my wifi router. But, unfortunately, the connection is somehow not persistent. So here is my setup:

I `ssh` into my raspberry while it is connected to USB. From here I created a `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` file with following content:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=DE
network={
  ssid="MYDEVICENAME"
  psk="MYDEVICEPASSWORD"
  key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
#fake network workaround for headless Raspberry Pi Zero
network={
  ssid="fakessid"
  psk="fakepass"
  key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

I don’t really remember where I got this from but it seems to work. Because I had no idea if it is relevant and saw both locations used, I copied the exact same thing one directory up to `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` (is that even necessary?)

I rebooted, but the Pi did not connect to the wifi by itself. So I found this command online:

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -Dwext -B
```

which did connect my Pi to the internet.
I also can ssh into it.
I also have internet as I can clone an online repo.
I can’t `apt-update` but I guess that’s probably a topic on its own.

But everytime I unplug it or reboot it, it won’t connect automatically and I’ll have to retype the above command.

How can I have the Raspberry Pi zero w connect to that network automatically every time it gets turned-on/booted?

I feel like it’s just one last small piece missing

Thank you!

Comment: You may have followed some other advice and modified other files, You should check [How to set up networking/WiFi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) and list any changes you made. The "fake" stuff does no harm, but is unnecessary - this was just to opinion of one user. You should only have 1 `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`

Comment: You can't `apt-update` because there is no such command.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I don’t know why but now it’s working, here is what I did:

I added this file:

```
sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant/conf
```

and placed these information inside:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=DE
network={
  ssid="MYDEVICENAME"
  psk="MYDEVICEPASSWORD"
  key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
#fake network workaround for headless Raspberry Pi Zero
network={
  ssid="fakessid"
  psk="fakepass"
  key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

only changing MYDEVICENAME and MYDEVICEPASSWORD to the correct values. I guess for others the country code might also have to be edited.

And then rebooting with

```
sudo reboot
```

I never used that command before but always rebooted using `sudo /sbin/shutdown -r now`, so it could also be that a proper `sudo reboot` what was needed.

So I have these settings now at 3 locations (`/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`, `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` and `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant/conf`) and also it feels as if I have to much information in these setting files.

I’m happy with the solution for now (after like 6 hours) but I’ll investigate this further (what is really needed).

Oh yes and I also found this link: https://www.piborg.org/blog/pi-zero-wifi-bluetooth and this one: https://brandonb.io/raspberry-pi-zero-w-headless-setup-on-macos maybe it helps someone.

Comment: You dont need wpa_supplicant/conf you just needed to reboot after making the changes to /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicanr.conf.